# how to parse string using json

Tags: android

this is jsonArray

```
     [{"0":"4363","record_id":"4363","1":"54621681","shop_id":"54621681","2":"25","category_id":"25","3":"","category1":"","4":"Dress 10012","product":"Dress 10012","5":"5000","price":"5000","6":"My Description\r\nMy Description\r\nMy Description\r\nMy Description","desc":"My Description\r\nMy Description\r\nMy Description\r\nMy Description","7":"http:\/\/www.shoppingmall.pk\/images\/menuimages\/54621681\/4363","products_image":"http:\/\/www.shoppingmall.pk\/images\/menuimages\/54621681\/4363","8":"1","status":"1","9":null,"external_link":null}]
```

i have to parse json array on thiz link
http://shops.alpha-trend.com/mobileapp/productinfo.php?productId=4363&function=GetProductInfo

Answer (score 1):

Use [JSONArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html).

```
try {
  JSONArray json = new JSONArray(json_string);
  json.getJSONObject(0).getString("1"); // == "54621681"
catch (JSONException e) {
  // ....
}
```

Comment: what i geve in place of thiz "json_string" in first line u defined?

Comment: I think you need to read some basic introduction to programming tutorials.  Start with something easier than Android - e.g. Visual Basic Express.

Comment: i got abt json_string nw its giving this error "Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of